# rxJava 2 undeliverable exception with threadpool and flatMap

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm getting an `UndeliverableException` when combining `subscribeOn` with `flatMap`. This minimal example illustrates the issue:

```
@Test
public void flatMapException() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    SettableFuture<Boolean> f = SettableFuture.create();

    Observable.just(1,2).flatMap(x -> {
        return Observable.just(1).flatMap(z -> {
            if (z == 1) return Observable.error(new IOException("haha"));
            return Observable.just(1);
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
    }).onErrorReturnItem(1).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).subscribe(
        x -> {}, 
        e -> {
            f.set(true);
        }, () -> {
            f.set(true);
        });

    assertEquals(true, f.get());
}
```

I expected that after the first error has been fired the Observable stops running and unsubscribes.

I would like only subscribe to the second Observable returned by the `flatMap` after the first has successfully finished.

How do I express my intention with RxJava ?

Comment: The `subscribeOn` makes the two subscriptions asynchronous thus you have a race from the first and second error observable. You could use the `delayErrors` parameter of the outer `flatMap` to collect both errors.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
  .map(x -> Observable.error(new Exception("e" + x)))
  .compose(xs -> Observable.concat(xs));
```